# How to set the Subversion revision number in Visual Studio build

Tags: visual-studio, svn, msbuild, build

I'd like to use the current Subversion revision number in my AssemblyFileVersion attribute to have this in the final complied dll.

I've used the [MsBuild Community Task library](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) from my deploy script to read the revision number and update the AssemblyInfo - this somewhat works, *but* ...

When I have an updated project and a current revsion number, say for example 100. I run the script and that will update the AssemblyInfo and a final dll with 100 as an attribute. When I then check these new AssemblyInfo files in I'll get a new revsion number (101).

The problem then is that if I see a dll with a specific revsion number and like to rebuild that dll the actual revsion I need is actually the one after the revsion numnber I see ...

How can this process be improved?

Comment: why do you need to check in the asssemblyinfo file? In the old days you might need it as a counter but if you always get your svn no its not needed?

Comment: Just a note that it's not a good idea, as the build number components are limited to a maximum number of 65534: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to use [RCS Keywords](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs701/Handouts/rcs_keywords.html)?

One of the keywords is `$Revision$`. This expands automatically to `$Revision:xxx$` where `xxx` is the Subversion revision number every time you do a `svn checkout` or `svn update`.

You'll have to set the property `svn:keywords` on your Assembly file in order for this to work:

```
$ svn propset svn:keywords Revision Assembly.cs
```

I do this all the time, but for the build server that runs our continuous build software. That's takes a bit of setting up, but it will automatically build the software, set the correct version number, and even deploy the software every time someone does a commit.

By the way, I take it you're using [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) as your Subversion integration for VisualStudio.